# How can I select something from a table and pass it into a variable?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
sqlstring = """
SELECT orderNo FROM tblOrder WHERE customerID = ? AND WHERE date = ?
    """

sqlstring = """
    INSERT INTO tblOrder_Line (costWhenPurchased,itemId,quantity,orderId) VALUES (
    (SELECT unitPrice FROM tblInventory WHERE itemID = ?),?,?,?)
    """
```

So I want to select `orderNo` from the order table but then I want to pass it as a variable so I can insert it into the order line table. How can I do this?

Comment: You don't repeat `WHERE` after `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Use another subquery, just like you did to get `costWhenPurchased`.

```
sqlstring = """
    INSERT INTO tblOrder_Line (costWhenPurchased,itemId,quantity,orderId) VALUES (
    (SELECT unitPrice FROM tblInventory WHERE itemID = ?),
    ?, ?,
    (SELECT orderNo FROM tblOrder WHERE customerID = ? AND date = ?))
    """
'''
```